# TypeError: iObj.fnprot is not a function

Tags: javascript, function, object, prototype, instance

In the following code why is there this error :

> TypeError: iObj.fnprot is not a function
>   on line 28:1.

```js
function Obj() {
  console.log(this.prototype);
  console.log(this.__proto__);
}

iObj = new Obj();

Obj.prototype.date = function() {
  return new Date();
}
console.log(iObj.date())

console.log(iObj.__proto__)
console.log(iObj.prototype)

console.log(iObj.__proto__)
console.log(iObj.prototype)

function notre_prototype() {
  this.fnprot = function() {
    console.log("Dans le nouveau prototype");
  }
}

iObj.prototype = notre_prototype;
console.log(iObj.prototype);
console.log(iObj.__proto__);

iObj.fnprot(); // The error lays here.
```

Comment: You should add some more context to your question.

Answer (score 0):

This would be the correct way to initialize your prototype:

```
iObj.prototype.fnprot = function(){
  console.log("Dans le nouveau prototype");
}
```

[Here](https://javascript.info/function-prototype) is a great tutorial on prototypes. If you have any further questions or need additional explanation, please don’t hesitate to ask.

Comment: I have tried this correction, but I got this error message :

     TypeError: iObj.prototype is undefined                        test.html:27:1

Any additional available help ?

Comment: @Jean-DadetDiasoluka could you please update the question with the current edition of the code?

Comment: <script>
    function Obj() {
      console.log(this.prototype);
      console.log(this.__proto__);
    }
    var iObj = new Obj();
    
    Obj.prototype.date = function() {
      return new Date();
    }
    console.log(iObj.date())
    console.log(iObj.__proto__)
    console.log(iObj.prototype)
    
    iObj.prototype.fnprot = function(){
      console.log("new proto");
    }
    
    console.log(iObj.prototype);
    console.log(iObj.__proto__);
    
    iObj.fnprot(); // The error
    </script>

    TypeError: iObj.prototype is undefined     test.html:32:1

Comment: @Jean-DadetDiasoluka move the line of code where you assign the prototype up (put it after `var iObj = …`)

Comment: @Jean-DadetDiasoluka btw I highly recommend you reading the tutorial, because your code is kinda strange

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks to me that .fnprot is not set to be a method on iObj in anyway. You did set iObj.prototype = notre_prototype, but not .fnprot

This is how you would se it:

```
iObj.prototype.fnprot = function(){
  console.log("Dans le nouveau prototype");
}
```

Comment: I have tried this correction, but now I got this error message :

     TypeError: iObj.prototype is undefined                        test.html:27:1

Any additional available help ?

Answer (score 0):

this is an [example](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_prototypes.asp) about working with prototype

and I think you should do it in this way

```
iObj.prototype.fnprot = function(){
  console.log("Dans le nouveau prototype");
}
```

Comment: I have tried this amendment, but I now got this error message :

     TypeError: iObj.prototype is undefined                        test.html:27:1

Any additional available help ?

Comment: This syntax did not work neither.
But why when I try the following syntax it seems to work ?

    iObj.fnprot=function() {
        console.log("Dans le nouveau prototype");
      }
    
without the word "prototype" !